# App icon shows as blank on real device using xcode 10

Tags: xcode, xcode10

As title states, my appicon shows up as blank on a real device when built with xcode 10 beta 1. It shows up properly next to the target name inside xcode 10 and when run on simulator. It also shows up properly on a real device if I build my project using xcode 9.4.

So far, I've tried:

- Removing the alpha property from the appicon asset files
- Changing the color profile of the appicon asset files to sRGB IEC61966-2.1
- Removing every pod dependency and deintegrating pods

I have tested on an iphone x and iphone 6s+ both running iOS 11.x.

I faced the same issue after creating a new project in xcode 9.4 and adding  only an appicon. I uploaded that project to https://github.com/shujew/AppIconNotAppearing

Can anyone assist?

Thanks

Comment: Same problem here (with iphone 6, 6Plus and 7). looks like a bug in xCode 10 to me.

Comment: Thanks for testing @Milander. While waiting for a possible workaround, I filed a bug report with apple (40851571) and on open radar (rdar://5605213490642944)

Comment: Same for me, building from Xcode 10 beta 1 to iOS 11.3 on iPhone X.

Comment: Try adding a new asset catalog for the App Icon in your xcassets, complete it, and set that as your app icon. They've changed the resolutions/required images.

Comment: @OscarApeland - I did this and saw no difference in the new asset catalog. The requirements were the same.

Comment: I did some digging to see if I could find my own workaround (exported a development IPA from Xcode10, then extracted the contents to inspect and compared against a known working IPA from Xcode 9.x.) All the Icon files are present. A comparison of the Info.plist showed nothing. I also verified both of the SHA hashes in the code signature file with the actual PNG file. Everything looks correct.

Comment: It has been a bug of the first beta of Xcode 10. In beta 2 the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your old app icon asset catalog and create a new one and try running it. It should display the app icon.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work either. I'm hoping Apple will address this soon.

Comment: Are you using any pods?

Comment: No pods at all. Please see github rep for exact code. It's a clean project with only icon assets added

Comment: Will take a look at it.